# Do In-App Purchase digital content have to be priced the same as if they were purchased through the web?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an app that is basically a reader. It reads third-party content (we are licensed to distribute this content) that the user purchased through the web for some price that was set by the third-party. Apple has expressed their desire that we implement In-App purchase, even though from my perspective it doesn't make a whole lot of sense. To be clear, my reader app follows guideline 3.1.3 and doesn't have any language or links that direct the user out of the app for purchasing.

My question is, if I implement In-App purchase, do I have to price the items being sold the same price as they're being sold on the web?

I am trying to find information about how IAP pricing works, and what the rules are.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, if I implement In-App purchase, do I have to price the
>   items being sold the same price as they're being sold on the web?

Not at all. I actually think it's common for apps that operate on some margins (Spotify, etc.) to price like this.

> Apple has expressed their desire that we implement In-App purchase,
>   even though from my perspective it doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

I know of apps that buried in-app purchases in settings to please Apple but don't even promote them with a paywall in the app. That said, even with the "Apple tax" in-app subscriptions may end up being a very lucrative channel if you haven't tried them with your app before.